# Prevent some view controller in a navigation controller from rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a navigation controller which displays two view controllers at once. They are layered and the front most controller can be dragged down to reveal the controller below.
My app delegate is configured so the app will only allow interface orientations when the view in the back is being revealed, as seen below.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.revealNavigationController.isViewRevealed)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Naturally this causes both the front and the back view controller to rotate when the device is rotated but I am only interested in rotating the back view controller.
Is there any way to completely disable rotation in the front most view controller?

Comment: Is your problem that the user can reveal the back view, rotate sideways, and then hide it and the primary view is still sideways, or that the primary view will get rotated even when it is offscreen?

Comment: @axiixc The problem is that the primary view is rotated when it is off screen. The view controller is not really meant to support orientation changes so if you reveal the back view, rotate to landscape, rotate back to portrait and hide the back view again so that the primary view is presented, the primary view is messed up. Ideally, I would want it to be impossible for the primary view to be rotated. This would solve both of the problems you mention. So if the user reveals the back view, rotates sideways and hides it, the primary view would still be portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution suggested by axiixc is generally better so depending on your problem, you should [look at his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310557/486845).** However, this did not solve my problem. I had a `UINavigationController` in which I inserted the view of a view controller as subview at index 0. This way, the view would be in the back. I had then made the `UINavigationBar` draggable so that when it dragged down, it would reveal the view in the back. The front most view would then move with the navigation bar.
I did not manage to get this to work with the view controller containment API introduced iOS 5, as suggested by axiixc.

Instead, I removed the view from the navigation controller and added it directly to the `UIWindow` when the app was launched and I handled the rotation of this view myself and disabled rotation on all other views (that is, I disabled it on the navigation controller).

This is how I added the view in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
self.revealViewController = [[RevealViewController alloc] init];
[self.window insertSubview:self.revealViewController.view atIndex:0];
```

Then, right after that I registered for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

My `didRotate:` looks like this: (this is inspired by another answer on StackOverflow which I am now unable to find again, sorry)

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Only rotate if the view is revealed
    if (self.revealNavigationController.isViewRevealed)
    {
        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
        [self updateForDeviceOrientation:orientation animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I call `-updateForDeviceOrientation:animated:`

```
- (void)updateForDeviceOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGFloat degrees = 0.0f;
    switch (orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            degrees = 90.0f;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            degrees = -90.0f;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            degrees = 0.0f;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    CGFloat duration = (animated) ? [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration : 0.0f;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        // Rotate view
        weakSelf.revealViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        weakSelf.revealViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees));

        // Resize view for rotation
        CGFloat width, height;
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
        {
            width = MAX(CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds));
            height = MIN(CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds));
        }
        else
        {
            width = MIN(CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds));
            height = MAX(CGRectGetWidth(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds));
        }

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

        CGRect viewBounds = weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds;
        viewBounds.size = newSize;
        weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds = viewBounds;

        CGRect viewFrame = weakSelf.revealViewController.view.frame;
        viewFrame.size = newSize;
        weakSelf.revealViewController.view.bounds = viewFrame;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the view controller containment APIs added in iOS5. Basically, what you need to do is remove your one view controller when you no longer want it to participate in the rotation events, and add it back when its ready again. A sample would be...

```
@implementation AXRotationDemoViewController

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.oneViewController = [[AXLoggingViewController alloc] init];
        self.oneViewController.interfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

        self.twoViewController = [[AXLoggingViewController alloc] init];
        self.twoViewController.interfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.oneViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:self.oneViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.oneViewController.view];
    [self.oneViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.twoViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:self.twoViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.twoViewController.view];
    [self.twoViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.oneViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.twoViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIButton * showBackButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [showBackButton setTitle:@"Toggle Back/Front" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [showBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(_toggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [showBackButton sizeToFit];
    showBackButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:showBackButton];
}

- (void)_toggle:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.childViewControllers containsObject:self.oneViewController])
    {
        [self.oneViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.oneViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.oneViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:self.oneViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.oneViewController.view];
        [self.oneViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        UIWindow * window = self.view.window;
        UIViewController * hack = window.rootViewController;
        window.rootViewController = nil;
        window.rootViewController = hack;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect halfScreenFrame = self.view.bounds;
    halfScreenFrame.size.height /= 2;

    self.oneViewController.view.frame = halfScreenFrame;
    self.twoViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(halfScreenFrame, 0, halfScreenFrame.size.height);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([self.childViewControllers containsObject:self.oneViewController])
        return self.oneViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;

    return self.twoViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}

@end
```

However you may notice, there is no official way to really tell iOS you've changed the value of `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, so your best bet is either a) use a hack like in my example above to force iOS to redo everything or b) don't let the user close the back view until the device is already in portrait again.

Here is the [sample](http://cl.ly/2J1G2u1n0a1h) I put together if that doesn't explain things well enough.

Comment: This would be the ideal approach but I did not manage to get this working in this case. For my solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354167/486845.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at the [-supportedInterfaceOrientations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW120) method in UIViewController. You return a [UIInterfaceOrientationMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientationMask) bitmask that specifies the orientations you want that UIViewController subclass to support.

Comment: I just tried returning `NO` in `-shouldAutorotate` and `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` in `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` in one of my front most controllers. While `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called when the view is presented but not on rotation, it seems to be ignored. The view controller still tries to rotate the view and satisfy my auto layout constraints in the landscape orientation.

Comment: `-shouldAutorotate` is not called, though.